# flutter error in loading Widget with multiple items dynamically Error

Tags: flutter

So i am getting this error and its doing my head in:
"Expected a value of type 'List', but got one of type List"

I am trying to load a list of selectable text widgets as as they can be 2 or 4 depending on the length of the list, this page is rendered dynamically.

Here is the code

```
Widget _answerField(BuildContext context) {
    //if type is true/false or MCQ,
    var state = Provider.of<EnrolmentDetailState>(context);

    if (widget.question.type == QuestionType.truefalse.value ||
        widget.question.type == QuestionType.multiplechoice.value) {
     //option looks awkward but returns a list of 2 items 'TRUE','FALSE' verified in debugging
      final options = jsonDecode(jsonDecode(widget.question.answer_options!));
      return Flexible(
          flex: 3,
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: options.map((opt) {
                return Container(
                  height: 90,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  color: Colors.black26,
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      state.selected = opt;
                      response.answer_options = opt;
                      //assign it to the value
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          state.selected == opt ? const Icon(Icons.check_circle_rounded, size: 30) : const Icon(Icons.radio_button_unchecked, size: 30),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                              child: Text(
                                opt,
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try casting options to List

```
final options = jsonDecode(jsonDecode(widget.question.answer_options!)) as List<String>;
```

now it returns dynamic so I guess that's why you get that error.